# How can i load and edit a customer profile in a RESTlet?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to write a Restlet in Suitescript 2.0 to get a customer record and edit its credit card field from an external mobile application. I access to the Restlet using a customer account and Oauth 2.0,  and I need get his own profile and edit it, but the response is :

"INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION\",\"message\":\"Permission Violation: You need  the \'Lists -> Customers\

I can't put the customer permission in List > Customers into the customer role, because netsuite platform doesn't allow it. So... How can i do it!?... Help me, please!

```
function editCustomerCreditCard(requestBody) {

        var user = requestBody.customer

        var customer = record.load({
            type: record.Type.CUSTOMER, 
            id: user.internalid,
            isDynamic: true
        });

        return JSON.stringify(customer)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do user-level permissions in the employee record.

Employee > Access > Global Permissions > Customers

Comment: Thanks! But, I can’t do it because i’m trying edit the customer profile from a customer account, not from a Employee account. I can’t give Global permission > Customer to a Customer account! That is the problem.

Comment: In that case you need to do the operation via Suitlet.